# com.facebook.react.commot.JavascriptException: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-tools

I'm trying to debug my android app with react native v0.66.1 and react native tools v1.8.1 in vsCode. But after running the app and attach to packager, or launch in debug mode,
I got this error `com.facebook.react.commot.JavascriptException: Invalid or unexpected token`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

update babel.config.js of your project : (assume your metro-react-native-babel-preset is 0.58.0)
from:

```
module.exports = {
   presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};
```

to:

```
module.exports = {
   presets: [['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset', {
        unstable_disableES6Transforms: true
    }]],
};
```

finally run yarn start --reset-cache to restart app.